# How do I create an array at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template<std::size_t sz>
constexpr std::array<int,sz> range(){
  std::array<int,sz> arr{0};
  std::iota(arr.begin(),arr.end(),0);
  return arr;
}
```

If I try to call it like

```
auto r = range<10>()
```

I'll get the following error

```
> $ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++1y main.cpp -o main && ./main                                                                                  
main.cpp:33:30: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<int, 10>'
constexpr std::array<int,sz> range(){
                             ^
main.cpp:48:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'range<10>' requested here
  auto r = range<10>();
           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__tuple:69:65: note: template is declared here
template <class _Tp, size_t _Size> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY array;
                                                                ^
main.cpp:34:22: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<int, 10>'
  std::array<int,sz> arr{0};
                     ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__tuple:69:65: note: template is declared here
template <class _Tp, size_t _Size> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY array;
                                                                ^
main.cpp:48:12: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::array<int, 10>'
  auto r = range<10>();
           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__tuple:69:65: note: template is declared here
template <class _Tp, size_t _Size> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY array;
                                                                ^
3 errors generated.
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: It seems you didn't `#include <array>`.

Comment: Note that your function does not apply for compile-time execution in C++11.

Comment: @chris But it should work in C++14 right?

Comment: @MaikKlein, It would if `std::iota` was `constexpr`. You can certainly make one.

Comment: `std::array`'s `begin()` and `end()` and non-const `operator[]` aren't `constexpr` either.

Comment: For actual `constexpr`-ness, you can use the usual `integer_sequence` trick: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a224faa56ddd808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to include

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc15a6715178a49b

Comment: Oh boy, that was embarrassing, thank you.